# iOS Documents Directory size limit

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating FTP download app that downloads into Documents Directory, and I have simple questions. Does the Documents Directory have size limit and does the download files stay there permanently until the app is removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about this, I had seen a comment in **discussions.apple.com** like:
**There is a limit of 2 GB.**

https://discussions.apple.com/message/7599983?messageID=7599983#7599983?messageID=7599983

**Files in the document directory stay there permanently until the app is removed.**

Answer (score 2):

**============EDIT=========**

**the fact is: 2Gb is the app size limit, and the app's directory can more than 2Gb;
I found it from apple [doc  is here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide_CN.pdf) , search keyword "2G"**

---

I don't know if apple did some change, I use an app named PPTV, it can store videos from server, and more than 2Gb; what happens?

Answer (score -1):

You should use Cache Directory if you want to cache anything without user's action or your app will get rejected if you dont follow the instructions:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html