# iOS Any Size Limits for Local Storage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storage

We are developing an in-house app which will have access to a large amount of image data which we would prefer to be off-line.

In short at first start-up the app will pull down the data from a server (around 3Gb) and then only get the data again when the user asks for an update.  I simply want to know if there are any size limits for persistent local storage?

Again note this is an in-house app for around 100 users and they are near servers with WiFi, all devices are iOS6, retina (new basically).  The updates will only be a few times a year and we may even code it so only changes are downloaded.

Comment: There is a 2GB App Bundle size limit, but I don't remember ever seeing documentation suggesting a limit to an App's document directory. Good news is, since it doesn't go through the app store, you can just build an app with quick dummy data and see if it throws any errors as you fill it.

Comment: Here is a related question. No concrete answers but they suggest something similar to what I've said with there being no documentation outside of normal app bundle limits. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154160/ios-documents-directory-size-limit

Comment: I am thinking of just doing just that, a quick app that will pull down massive directory of stuff just to see.  Someone below has done it but there is also download times and stuff I want to try.  Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 7):

There are no limits to the amount of data your app can store. We have apps pulling down over 10GB of data with no trouble.

The only thing you need to be careful of is storing the data in the Caches directory (or setting the 'do not backup' flag) to avoid it being backed up to iCloud if the user has that configured on their device.