# Does my app will be rejected if i store 1MB of sqlite db in NSDocument directory?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, hig

When the user taps on a button(say updateButton) the data will be downloaded and stored as a sqlite database in document directory. This data will be used whenever the user launches the app. I just want to know whether this app will be approved by appstore or not.

And also i want to know on the maximum size of the content inside the document directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well no your app will not be reject, I've got an app that downloads route for a server which can be up to 1GB. No problem there.

Just make sure that you flag them not to be included in the iCloud backup or store them in the cache directory.

Placing files in the cache directory has the draw back that if the system needs space it will delete files from the caches directory without notice.

Comment: It is absolutely necessary to flag big, static downloads etc. as "do not include in iCloud backup". They started enforcing this rule recently, and I had an app update rejected for this. App always did it, but now they started checking...

Comment: @AndersJohansen My document size is less than 5 mb, is it still necessary

Comment: It's really easy to do, and you should do it just to make sure. The point is to keep iPhone sync to iTunes and cloud quick, and I think that Apple pays for every byte that is sent back and forth to iCloud. They have an incentive to check, and so they will :) If not now, then later.

Comment: @rckoenes 
 
I have already uploaded the app into the appstore, it is in "Waiting for Review" thatswhy i am asking this question. Will they reject my app if i store a document content less than 5 MB without setting flag to it in document directory.

Comment: You can never tell with certainty whether or not an app will be rejected. But you should flag all files, that can be restore by the app, as not to backup in iCloud. All user generated files **should** be backuped to iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

`As per Apple Document, There will be noting in Document Directory when user just install the app. If the User launches the app, then you put anything in Document Directory.`

`You can use the all the free memory of the device for Document Directory.`

Comment: refer this [Document Directory][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154160/ios-documents-directory-size-limit].

Comment: I have already uploaded the app into the appstore, it is in "Waiting for Review" thatswhy i am asking this question. Will they reject my app if i store a document content less than 5 MB without setting flag to it in document directory.

Comment: @surendher, but when user install the app & not open the app then Document Directory must be Blank not even 10kb data. After that if user open the app then you can put the data in document directory.

Comment: I am creating a local sqlite database structure(size is 40 kb) in did finish launching method. Will they reject my app?

Comment: @surendher, I also crate a Sqlite Database on didfinishLaunch in lots of app, So don't worry they will not reject your app.

Comment: @user1673099 the 2GB limtis is the app bundle size, not the document directory size. There is not limit on the document directory size, it is only limited by the space available in the device.

Comment: Please Accept the Answer which is helpful to you. So, Any other user will get the right Direction if he faces the same issue.